# How to show an own text block when mouseover on a picture

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am learning html and I want that when we move the mouse into the picture, the elephant will be not shown any more. Instead there is a box (without border) with same size, inside the box there is certain text with blue background.
How should I change my code?

https://fiddle.jshell.net/66j07kyg/

Comment: that's a pig not an elephant, just FYI

Comment: @depperm: No, when we move the mouse into the pig, the elephant appears. And I want to make a box instead of the elephant.

Comment: since you are still learning can I give you a couple of hints? Do not use tables for layout. Use divs instead. Tables are for data representation only. Secondly do not use inline javascript but get used to write your own code outside the single html element

Comment: @LelioFaieta: thank you for your hint. Here I just took out a small part from my code. Normally i dont use table for layout. :) Actually, I have just learnt html for few days. So writing my own javascript code is not easy right now. To tell the truth, I copy this inline javascript.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include 
the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code  necessary 
to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem 
statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and 
Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: So you want a box instead of a elephant on mouseover?

Comment: @j08691: thank you, I edited my question. hope it is easier to read.

Comment: @depperm: yes, that is what I want to do.

Comment: I didn't say it wasn't easy to read, I said you need to put a [mcve] **in the question**, not just a link to jsFiddle.

Comment: @amateur , see my answer please!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
     
     $("td").mouseenter(function(){
         
         $("img").css({display:"none"});
         $(".txt").show();
          $(this).css({verticalAlign:"top",backgroundColor:"blue"})
         
     }).mouseleave(function(){
         
         $("img").css({display:"block"});
         $(".txt").hide();
         $(this).css({backgroundColor:""})
        
   })
     
 })
```

```css
img {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

td {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
 }
.txt {
  display: none;
  color: #fff;
 }
```

```html
 <table align='center'>
   <tr>
     <td>
       <img src="http://gdbaif.com/images/animal-clipart/animal-clipart-02.jpg"/>
       <span class="txt">This is some text</span>
     </td>
 </tr>
</table>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: thank you @ehsan, I have some more questions. 1. If I do not use table any more (so there is no `td` before `<img ....>` in html code any more, how should I change the javascript code above? 2. When I use your code for 2 pictures, this effect is for both pictures, how can I use this effect for each picture without affecting the other one? 3. In my html code, where should I put the javascript code above (before or at the end of body)? https://fiddle.jshell.net/nd88zLbn/1/

Comment: In your CSS code you set parameter for `img`. So if I have other pictures somewhere else and I also use for example `<img src="C://pictures/02.jpg"/>`, then this picture also has the fixed size (200px * 200px)?

Comment: You can use a id for this img and use `$("#YourId")` instead of `$("img")` .

Comment: 1)you must use event `mouseenter` and ` mouseleave` for element that you want.for example if image be in `<div>`, you must use  `$("div").mouseenter(function()`

Comment: 2)You must use different ids for each image